# Problem importing .eps files from ChemDraw 20 (MikTeX 4.6; TexMaker 5.1.2) and chemnum won't work

Tags: psfrag, chemnum

relative newbie writing my thesis using ChemDraw 20 for structures, including different chapter using \include. I can't seem to be able to import .eps files from chemdraw into my main file. Under the 'equation' environemnt, I get two empty pages in the output pdf, and in the 'figure' or 'scheme' environment, nothing happens. In another file using the same preamble, I can at least import the image, but the TMP tags aren't replaced.

During compilation I see 'miketex-makepk did not succeed', 'Ghostscript 9.25 error: exit code 1', 'dvips: font  not found in mapping file, characters will be left blank'.

Quickbuild: PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf

PdfLaTex: pdflatex -enable-write18 -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

dvips: dvips -u +builtin35 -Pdownload35 -o %.ps %.dvi

Dvipdfm: dvipdfm %.dvi

ps2pdf: ps2pdf %.ps

ghostscript: "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.21/bin/gswin32c.exe"

Also, I can't figure out how to include the .eps file, so here's a picture of it:
[image: .png format]

I'd be really grateful for help; been struggling with this for a while now!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,english,bibliography=totocnumbered,pointessnumbers]{scrbook}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,foot=15mm,bmargin=35mm,a4paper} %Seitenränder
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,format=hang,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{ulem} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{colortbl}



\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}%Fußnoten in Tabellen
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-heading=\section{#1},
list-name={Fußnoten},
list-style = itemize,
counter-format=roman}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %für chemische Formeln
\usepackage[autocite=superscript,backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\makeatletter

\protected\long\def\blx@imc@mkbibemph#1{%Buchtitel wird nun kursiv statt unterstrichen
\textit{#1}\blx@imc@setpunctfont\textit}
\makeatother
\let\mkbibemph\mkbibitalic 

\addbibresource{Thesis.bib}




\usepackage{chemnum} %number chemical structures
\setchemnum{format=\sffamily\bfseries\small,replace-tag={TMP}}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf} % Use EPS graphics with pdfLaTeX.
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{} %to remove the word 'chapter' from the heading, so that it says '1.Introduction', and not 'Chapter 1. Introduction'

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} 
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1}

\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\makenomenclature

%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titleref}%Textverweise
\labelformat{figure}{Figure~#1}
\labelformat{table}{Table~#1} 
\labelformat{scheme}{Scheme~#1} 
\labelformat{equation}{Equation~#1}
\labelformat{section}{Section~#1}
\labelformat{subsection}{Subsection~#1}
\labelformat{subsubsection}{Subsection~#1}
\labelformat{footnote}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\labelformat{endnote}{\textsuperscript{#1}}


\newcounter{GeneralProcedure} \setcounter{GeneralProcedure}{0}
\renewcommand{\theGeneralProcedure}{\textbf{\Alph{GeneralProcedure}}}
\newcommand{\GP}[1]{\refstepcounter{GeneralProcedure} \label{GP:#1}}

%Absätzlich nicht ans Ende der Seite strecken
\raggedbottom
%Zeilenspacing
\onehalfspacing




\newcommand{\via}{\textit{via }}


\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\clubpenalty = 10000 
\widowpenalty = 10000


\usepackage[colorlinks,
          pdfpagelabels,
          pdfstartview = FitH,
          bookmarksopen = true,
          bookmarksnumbered = true,
          linkcolor = black,
          plainpages = false,
          hypertexnames = false,
          citecolor = black] {hyperref}  

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\centering
\replacecmpd{dimethylacetlyenecarboxylate}
\replacecmpd{diphenyldiselenide}
\replacecmpd{producta}
\replacecmpd{productb}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{./Images/Equations/eqn_1.4.eps} 
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:eqn1.4_selenoradicaltoalkyne}
\end{equation}

\end {document}
```